# Does ZFC have an intended interpretation?

Tags: set-theory, philosophy

I know that PA has an intended interpretation, namely $\mathbb{N}$, and the usual axioms of the real line have an intended interpretation, namely $\mathbb{R}$. Does ZFC have an intended interpretation?

Comment: Related, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189466/how-to-exhibit-models-of-set-theory/ (my answer, I think, covers this question as well)

Comment: I would think this question is more philosophical than anything. You may want to add the (philosophy) tag. Some people think yes, there is an intended interpretation, and our goal as set theorists is to clarify its properties, in particular by identifying its features beyond the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms. It is not a universally held view, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, you write: "If we have a canonical model of ZFC then we essentially solved all independence questions." I don't think this is quite right. True, for any particular model every sentence will either hold, or it won't; however, we may not be able to tell which possibility is actually realized. For instance, GCH may be true in the canonical model according to TG+GCH, and GCH may be false in the canonical model according to TG+$\neg$ CH.

Comment: But you didn't ask about an intended interpretation of $\sf ZFC+GCH$. You asked about $\sf ZFC$. Much like the fact that Goodstein's theorem is "true", but not "provable"; having an intended interpretation would mean that $\sf GCH$ is true/false but not provable.

Comment: Well i could be wrong  im not a set theorist, but i think youd have to build that canonical model within a more powerful theory. Depending on the theory chosen, you'll be able to prove different sentences are satisfied by that canonical model.

Comment: @Asaf, i think you may have misinterpreted my first comment...... Notice i mentioned TG.

Comment: And your question said "$\sf ZFC$". But what difference does that make? $\sf TG$ is an extension of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: Well my question is about ZFC. We can build a canonical model of ZFC in a more powerful theory, eg TG.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, sorry am I completely wrong? If you're very certain that I'm wrong, I'll defer to your better judgment.

Comment: I'm still trying to formulate a proper rebuttal, the difficulty is psychological and philosophical. And I feel that any answer would invariably end up "speaking for everyone" where I can only speak for myself. I'll give it some more thought, and when I'm finished preparing the lecture for Sunday I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Asaf, well don't let me keep you. It suddenly occurs to me I should be working on my algebra assignment.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. The intended interpretation of ZFC is the class of all hereditary well-founded sets. This class is often called the [von Neumann universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Comment: Is the CH true or false in that model?

Comment: @kinokijuf: :)  ${}{}{}{}$