# $\Sigma\subset Th(\mathbb{N})$ is finite, so $\Sigma$ has $2^{\aleph_0}$ non-isomorphic models

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I want to prove the statement in the title using Godel's theorems.
Without Godel's theorem, I may use the theorem about infinite model from cardinality $\kappa$ $\Rightarrow$ infinite models from any cardinality $>\kappa$ to get as many non-isomorphic models as I wish (cause $\mathbb{N} \models \Sigma$)

I was trying to use Godel's theorem in the next manner, every recursive $\Sigma \subset Th(\mathbb{N})$ is not complete (and so for finite subsets as they are recursive), therefore one can find sentence $\alpha$ such that $\Sigma\nvdash \alpha , \neg\alpha$ so $\Sigma\cup\alpha$ , $\Sigma\cup\neg\alpha$ has models $M_1 , M_2$ because there are consistent ($\Sigma\subset Th(\mathbb{N})$  and therefore consistent ) . $M_1,M_2$ are not isomorphic cause they are not elementary equivalent.

I don't find an Idea to generalize this approach to get $2^{\aleph_0}$ models, any other approach will be appreciated, as long as it is using Godel's theorems

Comment: For yet another approach, Andrés' comment on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/638454/14366) suggests a compactness-based argument that $\mathbb N$ (or any other model of Q) has continuum many nonisomorphic countable _elementary extensions_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this idea to build a whole infinite binary tree of theories.

At each node in the tree you have a finite set of sentences $B$ such that $PA+\Sigma+B$ is consistent. Apply the Gödel-Rosser construction to this theory to get an undetermined $\alpha$. The two successors of the node will arise by appending either $\alpha$ or $\neg\alpha$ to $B$.

The tree has countably many *nodes*, but $2^{\aleph_0}$ many *infinite branches*. Each branch has a model thanks to compactness. The models of two different infinite branches are non-isomorphic because they disagree about the $\alpha$ where their branches diverge from each other.

Comment: I am having some trouble with "models of two different branched are non-isomorphic" - when branching - the descendants of $M\models \Sigma$ , $M_1\models \Sigma \cup \alpha, M_2\models \Sigma\cup\neg\alpha$ are non isomorphic but potentially one of them might be isomorphic to $M$ from which they were branched, so maybe this process doesn't result with $2^\aleph_0$ models which are not isomorphic in pairs (every 2 are non-isomorphic to each other)

Comment: @dan: Sorry, sloppy phrasing on my part. I'm really only considering models for the _infinite_ branches -- I don't count models of the _finite_ intermediate steps at all. So in your example, $M$ is not counted in its own right among the $2^{\aleph_0}$ models.

Comment: Look at the models of the complete theories resulting from complete branches, not models of the partial theories corresponding to the nodes along the way.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Careful with that phrasing too -- the theories corresponding to infinite branches are not all "complete".

Comment: They are if you build the tree the natural way :-)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Depends on which way is "natural", of course. If I had said "take the shortest yet-undecided $\alpha$" at each node, then you're right -- but since I said "apply Gödel's construction", there's a risk that innocent readers might think that deciding just all of the successive Gödel sentences would produce a complete theory.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Second thoughts regarding the binary tree building - as I was taught Godel theorem applied for $\Sigma\subset Th(\mathbb{N})$ which are recursive - if so - when we branch for $\Sigma \cup \alpha$, $\Sigma \cup \neg\alpha$ because $Th(\mathbb{N})$ containn $\alpha$ xor $\neg\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ we get that $\Sigma \cup \alpha$ or $\Sigma \cup \neg \alpha$   (one of them) are not subsets of $Th(\mathbb{N})$, so we can't use Godle's theory to proceed the binary tree building from this branch. Is my understanding of Godel's theorem is wrong?

Comment: @dan: Good point. There are several variant statements of the incompleteness theorem to be found in different books. Requiring that $\Sigma$ is true in $\mathbb N$ is a stronger premise than you actually need, but is easy to _explain_ so is found in some nontechnical presentations.

Comment: In Gödel's original work the condition was that $\Sigma$ is "$\omega$-consistent", which is a rather technical property that he could argue is "obviously true" for a theory that is true about the actual integers. Later Rosser improved the construction so it now works for any $\Sigma$ that is merely _consistent_ and contains sufficiently much arithmetic, no matter if it is true in $\mathbb N$. That's what I actually meant when I said "Gödel's construction".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks, do you have a reference for Rosser's improvement? I wish to read about it.

Comment: @dan: See e.g. section 51 of Peter Smith's [Gödel Without (Too Many) Tears](http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/godel-without-tears/).